# How to sort and update dropzone images order using sortablejs?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, sortablejs

I am working with dropzone with sortablejs, but i am unable to get updated array of files after sort. Sorting is working fine. Please guide me where i am wrong. Below is my code.

```
  var dropzone = new Dropzone('#dropzone', {
        url: '/canvas/ajax',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
        dictRemoveFileConfirmation: 'Do you really want to remove this file?',
        init: function() {
            load_props()
            var newQueue = [];
            var submitButton = document.querySelector("#prop_list button")
            myDropzone = this;
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            })
            this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append('instance_id', '<?php echo $instance_id; ?>') // Passing instance id with the props
            });
            this.on('removedfile', function(file) {
                const id = {
                    id: file._removeLink.dataset.id
                }
            });
            var el = document.getElementById('dropzone')
            var sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
                animation: 150,
                group: 'props',
                cursor: 'move',
                sort: true,
                draggable: '.dz-preview',
                ghostclass: 'ghost',
                filter: '.dz-message',
                onSort: function(evt) {
                   
                }
            })
        },
    });
```

Any solution appreciated!